# What is the signification of -f in scp command?

Tags: java, scp, sshj

I'm using the library [sshj](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj) for sending an scp command. It uses the option -f for downloading from a server to another. I can't find the -f option in the man.

What is the signification of -f in an scp command?

Comment: Can you provide us the code for this?  I shouldn't need to be digging it up.

Comment: scp has -f and -t options, but they're not intended for end-user use. IIRC, scp the client application requests ssh-server-side invocations of scp with these options to send and receive individual files. (Note, I've made no attempt to verify my recollection.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`-f` and `-t` are undocumented switches which tell the remote `scp` to send or prepare to receive a file or files from the local `scp`.

[This site](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch03_08.htm) explains it in slightly more detail in section *3.8.1. scp1 Details*:

> That copy is invoked with the undocumented switches -t and -f (for "to" and "from"), putting it into SCP1 server mode. This next table shows some examples; Figure 3-6 shows the details.
>
> ```
> This client scp command:      Runs this remote command:
> scp foo server:bar            scp -t bar
> scp server:bar foo            scp -f bar
> scp *.txt server:dir          scp -d -t dir
> ```